# problems when reading file and importing data into graph

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a Weighted Graph in C that stores data of bus stops, problems arises when Im trying to read the text file into the graph.
for more context the graph use red and black tree to store data of vertices and edges and the text file content look sth like this:

```
bus stop 1>bus stop 2>bus stop 3
bus stop 2>bus stop 4>bus stop 5
```

I use a loop of 2 strtok() function to extract each bus stop:

```
int n=0;   
Graph g = createGraph();
const char delim[2]="\n";
const char dl[2]=">";   
FILE *fptr;

if((fptr = fopen("station.txt", "r")) == NULL)
{
    printf("cannot open file!\n");
    exit(1);
}

while(fgets(line,200,fptr)!=NULL)
{
    tach=strtok(line,delim);
    while( tach!= NULL)
    {
        tachtach=strtok(tach,dl);
        while (tachtach!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n",tachtach);
            tachtach=strtok(NULL,dl);
            addVertex(g,n,tachtach);
            n++;
        }
        tach= strtok(NULL,delim);
    }
}
```

without the `addVertex()` api which literally just add vertice to the graph it print out every bus stop like normal which should look like this

```
bus stop 1
bus stop 2
bus stop 3
bus stop 2
bus stop 4 
bus stop 5
```

however when I try to use the `addVertex()` api it just returns the first line and then it say `seggmentation fault(core dumped)`
if I add just 1 vertice with `addVertex(g,0,data)` it adds a vertice to graph `g` with a lable that stores in data and the key of the vertice is `0`. If I use this however in the loop like

```
while(fgets(line,200,fptr)!=NULL)
{
    tach=strtok(line,delim);
    while( tach!= NULL)
    {
        tachtach=strtok(tach,dl);
        while (tachtach!=NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n",tachtach);
            tachtach=strtok(NULL,dl);
            addVertex(g,0,tachtach);
        }
        tach= strtok(NULL,delim);
    }
}
```

it will go through all the bus stop but only add the info of the second bus stop to the vertice `0`.
I think the problem is with the integer `n` when I try to use it in the while loop but I'm not sure what it is that's wrong.

Comment: You cannot "nest" `strtok` sessions because they can only store state for one session at once. If `strtok_r` is available on your platform, you could use that instead.

Comment: You don't show how `n` is defined or initialized. Please [edit] your questionand create a [mre].

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding what [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) does. It reads a *single* line, which means `tach= strtok(NULL,delim);` would not make any sense.

Comment: thanks, I have tried using strtok_r and reduce down to one loop since fgets have already read one line at a time so the  "\n" delimiter is unnecessary then it worked perfectly fine, big thanks to all of of you!!